# QoS DSCP problems when sending traffic with iperf3 to Windows Host

Tags: virtualbox, qos, iperf

I am encountering a problem with capturing traffic generated from a virtual machine (CentOS 6) using iperf3.

Before sending the traffic (UDP) to the iperf3 server running on the Windows 10, I use a DSMARK qdisc and iptables to mark it on the DSCP field with different values. When capturing the received traffic in Wireshark on Windows, the DSCP value for each packet is 0. I think Windows or VirtualBox is messing with it somehow. Any idea why this might be happening?

When capturing the outgoing packets with tcpdump, I can see the DSCP values set properly.

Comment: How do you have VirtualBox's networking set up? I could  imagine bridged mode would be better than NAT mode as it avoids more of the host OS's networking stack. Also, it would help to know the network path between the two devices.

Comment: unfortunately, due to the protocol analyzer i'm using (besides wireshark) to visualize the data, i am forced to use nat mode and capture on the loopback interface.

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12309 the NAT issue of not preserving the TOS field was identified 7-8 years ago, should have been fixed, but i am unsure of that